# Binding ajax function(data) to div id while form submission binds empty table with result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After form submission the data retrieved from php code is returned in ajax function.
When I bind the return response to `id="result"` HTML, I get result with empty form as well.

[Please refer to this image][1]

How can I only remove empty form binding with `#result`

**HTML code and php ** :

```
<?php
    
            $successMessage=""; $error="";
            
            
            if($_POST){
                    if (!$_POST["email"]) {
            
                        $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";
                        
                    }
                    if (!$_POST["message"]) {
                        $error .= "The message field is required.<br>";
                    }
        
                    if (!$_POST["subject"]) {
                       $error .= "The subject is required.<br>";
                        
                    }
                    
                     if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                        
                        $error .= "The email address is invalid.<br>";
                    
                        
                    } 
        
                    if ($error != "") {
                    

                    $error= "oops error";
                    
                    echo "$error" ;
                    
                    }   
                    
                    else {
                   
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    
                    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

                    $message= $_POST['message'];
                    
                    
                    $emailTo = "infor@thewellnessfirst.com";
                    
                    $from = "inquiry@thewellnessfirst.com" ;
                    
                   
                
                    $headers = 'From: '.$from. "\n" .  'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .

                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                    
                    if (mail($emailTo , $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                        
                        $successMessage ="email sent";
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        
                     $successMessage = "there is an arror please try later"; 
                     
                    } 
                    echo " $successMessage" ;
                    
                    }
                    
                    
            }
    ?>


    <form class="form" action="" method="post" id="myform">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"><br>
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit"  value="submit" >Send</button><br>
        <textarea  type ="text" id="response" style="width:200px ; height:200px;"></textarea>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var content = "";
                $.post("ajax.php", {
                        message: $('#message').val(),
                        subject: $('#subject').val(),
                        email: $('#email').val()
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        $("#result").append(data);
                    });
                $("#myform")[0].reset();
            });
        });
    </script>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1wa8.png
```

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question? Its not clear what you expect to happen and how that fails

Comment: Yes of course!! when i submit form (empty/filled) i get error/success message in Ajax response ie Function(data) . But when i append the data returned to div id="result" , i get the result and an empty form. i just want result only.

Comment: Your `ajax.php` should not be sending the HTML for that form

Comment: So you saying it may be error in php? It’s just simple php

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution ..we just need to add  exit(); in end of php script